# Was any data actually transmitted between OSCD and ISARA in the recent CubeSat lasercom test?

Tags: cubesat, laser, marco-cubesats

Two CubeSats (the [OCSD](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/small_spacecraft/ocsd_project.html) and [ISARA](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/spacetech/small_spacecraft/isara_project.html) CubeSats) recently [demonstrated](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7371) technology for on-orbit sat-sat laser communications. All the information I have been able to find doesn't indicate if the test actually transmitted data or just demonstrated that a link could be established.

The article states that "The optical communications beam was deliberately aimed at and swept across the ISARA camera. This demonstration shows that an optical crosslink between two CubeSats is feasible with proper pointing and alignment of the emitting and receiving spacecraft." The hardest part of laser com is the extremely high pointing constraints, so if those were not demonstrated what does this actually prove? It seems to me that not a whole lot of data could be encoded in a brief sweep.

Comment: What is a marco-cubesat? A typo of a macro-cubesat?

Comment: Just a CubeSat that has similarities to the Marco-Spacecraft. ISARA was the CubeSat the proved the innovative antenna used on Marco